# Visual Studio 2017 - how to set the installation directory

Tags: cmake, visual-studio-2017

I need to build a library on Windows. I generate a sln file using cmake:

```
cmake -G "Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64" CMakeLists.txt
```

Then I open sln file in Visual Studio and I build the solution. There is `INSTALL.vcxproj`. It looks like I should run it because "include" directory for that lib is not separated. How I can set the installation directory in Visual Studio ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the cache variable [`CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX.html) to the directory you want to install to via the install target when setting up the project.

Furthermore you should specify the directory containing the `CMakeLists.txt` file, not the file itself (in source builds are usually not a good idea anyways.

```
cmake -G "Visual Studio 15 2017" -A x64 -D "CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=C:/Program Files/some_dir" source_dir
```

Note that the path for installing from a package can be set seperately, if you're planing to use the `PACK` target/cpack; Use [CPACK_PACKAGING_INSTALL_PREFIX](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CPACK_PACKAGING_INSTALL_PREFIX.html) for this purpose.

Btw: Usually the files from the include directory are available regardless of whether you install the target or not via `INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` target property of the target, so if you link the library using `target_link_libraries`, the include directories should be available; At least that's the case, if the library is properly set up.

Comment: Is it possible to modify an install prefix from Visual Studio ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you cannot do this. If the install prefix is already in the cache, you could modify it using cmake-gui with the build directory as parameter. You could make sure this is the case by adding `set(CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX "${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}" CACHE PATH "The path to install to using the install target")` If you really want and you're sure the user has installed cmake-gui (does not come with the cmake installation on e.g. ubuntu), you could add a custom target for configuration that launches cmake-gui with `CMAKE_BINARY_DIR` as parameter when it's built.